# Setting background color of rangeSelector container in Highstock/Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart and I need to modify the `rangeSelector` section. I've been able to format some of the buttons and input boxes, but I'd like to **specify the background color of the entire range selection area**. Here's an image of the area I'm talking about (red outline).

[image]

Additionally, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QeDGC/4/) for that particular chart.

As far as I can tell, there are no options that would allow me to select that section directly [listed in the documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector).

I've also tried making a div and positioning it absolutely over the range selector, and then elevating the elements inside the range selector with the Highcharts `zIndex` attribute, but that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to render a rect element, which will be a background for the `rangeSelector`:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var rangSel = this.rangeSelector.group.getBBox();

            this.renderer.rect(
                rangSel.x,
                rangSel.y,
                rangSel.width,
                rangSel.height
            ).attr({
                fill: 'red'
            }).add();
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kpbxya8s/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Answer (score 0):

Found a good workaround in case anyone runs into this issue as well. Set the chart's overall `backgroundColor` to a linear gradient with three stops (the first two are your initial color). Here's an example where the top bar needs to be 54px tall.

```
backgroundColor: {
  linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 54],
  stops: [
    [0, '#707070'],
    [1, '#707070'],
    [2, '#e2e2e2']
  ]
},
```